# using playframework how to list values

Tags: scala, playframework

get an error

Cannot use a method returning Unit as an Handler

inside Application

```
def listAllFriends(userId:Long){
    val myfriend:List[MyFriend]=MyFriend.listAllFriendByUser(userId)
    Ok(views.html.allFriends.render(myfriend))

  }
```

in views page

```
@(myFriends: List[MyFriend])

@for(myFriend <- myFriends){
    @myFriend.friend_Id <br>
}
```

In routes

```
GET  /allFriend     controllers.Application.listAllFriends(postId:Long)
```

And in model

model have myfriend got 4 values id,userId,friendId and isAccept. userId and FriendId are the ForeignKey from table UserProfile..

```
def listAllFriendByUser(user_Id:Long):List[MyFriend]={
     DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
     val friendByUser= SQL(
         """
     select * from MY_FRIEND where USER_ID ={user_Id}   
     """).on(
         'user_Id -> user_Id).as(MyFriend.simple.*)  
         friendByUser
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In routes, try :

```
  POST /allFriends        controllers.Application.listAllFriends(userId:Long)
```

See [Play 2.0 framework - POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007957/play-2-0-framework-post-parameters)

And in Application, you have missed the 'Action' :

```
def listAllFriends(userId:Long) = Action {...}
```

Comment: i try that an got Compilation Cannot use a method returning Unit as an Handler

Comment: the error was gone and i got Action not found
any other code section  i missed

Comment: import play.api.mvc.Action ?

Comment: i'am sorry to say Thanx... and  i import that and no change i think any other coding section will missed

Comment: There is No error but the page shows Action not found

For request 'GET /allPosts'

Comment: If you want a GET, put GET and not POST in the routes file

Comment: I didn't write a Get method for that

Comment: A listSomething method is a GET, I suppose, not a POST.

Comment: is GET Method contain parameters?

Comment: I use GET And their Parameters but this problem occured 
Bad request
For request 'GET /allFriends' [Missing parameter: postId]

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file you call the method listAllFriends() without argument, while it is defined as def listAllFriends(userId:Long). You must pass it the userId parameter...

Comment: i try that an got Compilation Cannot use a method returning Unit as an Handler