# AngularJS http sending post request fails

Tags: angularjs, playframework

Having this GET request, it works (sends request to the sever and server is able to handle it):

```
    /* post to server*/
    $http.get("/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm/" + JSON.stringify(data)).
        success(function(data) {
            console.log("good")
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("something wrong")
        })
```

When I use this POST request it doesn't.

```
 $http.post("/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm/" + JSON.stringify(data)).
                success(function(data) {
                    console.log("good")
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("something wrong")
                })
```

or writing in different form:

```
           $http({
                url: '/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm',
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("good")
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("something wrong")
            });
```

What I have in the end is:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Requested payload is json: `{"name":"name1","surname":"surname1"}`

On the server (playframework) I defined routes that are supposed to accept client calls.

```
GET        /forms/FormValidator1/validateForm/:jsonForm           controllers.FormValidator1.validateForm(jsonForm:String)

POST        /forms/FormValidator1/validateForm/:jsonForm            controllers.FormValidator1.validateForm(jsonForm:String)
```

Or with no `":jsonForm"`

```
 POST        /forms/FormValidator1/validateForm            controllers.FormValidator1.validateForm(jsonForm:String)
```

What might be the reason. What I missed?

**UPDATE**

Interestly enough: after I got it working on my laptop (see my answer below) then push it on gitHub and pull it to another machine it starts working differently. Now it complains than **Bad Request** is [Invalid XML] nevertheless I use `"application/json"` header and did not change any line of code after commit. I wonder maybe it is a **bug**.

It seems along `DocumentType`, I need provide `dataType : 'json'`, but since Play wants it be in the url. This all does not work.

Comment: In your update, the `controllers.FormValidator1.validateForm` still takes `jsonForm` as an argument. I thought that would not compile.

Comment: It compiles. You may try: https://github.com/Sergey80/angularjs-examples/blob/master/conf/routes

in that version I've commented POST for now.

Comment: I see, as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007957/play-2-0-framework-post-parameters), playframework will assume that the field `jsonData` will be present in the `data`. Then maybe your `data` in the POST request should look like: `data: {'jsonForm' : JSON.stringify(data) }` ?

Answer (score 1):

The server configuration accepts *POST* requests on URLs of the form: `/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm/:jsonForm`.

The URL the client is *POSTing* to is`/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm/`, which does not fit that form (note the missing `:jsonForm`).

Comment: I suppose that my 'data' stands for that ':jsonForm'.. that's why. If I put: "POST        /forms/FormValidator1/validateForm" (without ':jsonForm') it will not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with an answer related to `playframework`, which fixes my/this issue.

Here it is:
[Playframework handling post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941786/playframework-handling-post-reqeust/19944146#19944146)

See **UPDATE 2** section there.

The point is:

1. On Angualar side: No need to use params at all while building url. Just general approach with `data`
2. And on server side use Play' [bodyParser](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaBodyParsers) to extract data, whatever was passed as a body of request.