# Using POST routes parameters in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a login route that should transmit its input parameters as POST variables. I have defined my route like this:

```
POST    /v1/accounts/login          controllers.v1.Accounts.login(username: String, password: String)
```

and my Controller is like this:

```
object Accounts extends Controller {
  def login(username: String, password: String) = Action {
    Ok("Foo " + username)
  }
}
```

When I test this route using Chromes [Advance REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) it only works for GET parameters and not if I send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST form data.

The [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting) never actually mentions POST parameters but neither does it say that it does not work.

I think it might get it to work if I create a Form and bind my request to that but that seems needlessly complex.

Is there really no way to bind POST parameters using the routes file?

Comment: I just noticed this: `If the action method defines some parameters, all these parameter values will be searched for in the request URI, either extracted from the URI path itself, or from the query string` so I guess it really does not work with POST parameters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Route = resolving params inside the URL = sending params via GET.

That means, that you are trying to send  POST request by... GET params... where's the sense ?

**James Roper** explains that:

> *At routing time, Play hasn't yet consumed the request body, and so hasn't parsed the submitted form. - and you don't want it to either, because it's your action that decides how/whether the request body gets parsed, streamed, sent elsewhere, if Play did this at routing time, it would limit what you could do in an action.*

From security point of view it's definitely bad idea to leave credentials in logs of every machine in the path of client.

Instead you should do it with common form handling way like described in [base form documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms):

route:

```
POST    /v1/accounts/login      controllers.v1.Accounts.login
```

action:

```
val userForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "username" -> text,
    "password" -> text
  )
)

def login = Action { implicit request =>
  val (username, password) = userForm.bindFromRequest.get
  Ok("Hello " + username + ", you're trying to login with: " + password)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the Log file was one of the reasons GET parameters was not acceptable. 

So it is like I suspected, automatic parameter binding only works for GET parameters, too bad.

Comment: That's not so dramatic approach just few lines more, if you'll use more advanced Form ie. with predefined constraints you will additionaly increase security, you can just check if username has required length or if is it email etc. ;) thumbs up!

Comment: At routing time, Play hasn't yet consumed the request body, and so hasn't parsed the submitted form. - and you don't want it to either, because it's your action that decides how/whether the request body gets parsed, streamed, sent elsewhere, if Play did this at routing time, it would limit what you could do in an action.

Comment: @biesior but example somme javascript UI provided only 1 url end point and force developer using POST, so to execute some task need get value from POST request then decide route  to which controller. Real example 
[Extjs Direct](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/backend_connectors/direct/specification.html)